# Closing mail view controller upon clicking Cancel or Delete Draft

Tags: swift, xcode, email

I created a Mail Controller in my application, it works perfectly, the sending part is fine as well. But when I click on "Cancel" or "Delete Draft" the window wont close and it basically gets stuck on the email screen.

I tried searching, all the fixes did not work. Here is my code.

```
@IBAction func btnEmail(_ sender: Any)
    {

    let mailCompose = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailCompose.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailCompose.setToRecipients(["issam.barakat@hct.ac.ae"])
    mailCompose.setSubject("Amazing Health App!")
    mailCompose.setMessageBody("This application is amazing, keep it up!", isHTML: false)

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    {
        self.present(mailCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: make sure you are conforming to Delegate..

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: please inherit / Conform to Protocol MFMailComposeViewCOntrollerDelegate  ...
and in your code   mailCompose.delegate = self

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Salam Abdul Waheed, could you clarify please? Not sure what I need to do. Could you guide me please

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we need to import the MessageUI module.

Second, we need to specify that the View Controller will conform to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol. Later, we’ll actually implement the method that this protocol outlines, which will allow us to make the email composer screen go away once the user is finished either sending an e-mail or cancels out of sending one.
try this..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
    mailComposerVC.delegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["someone@somewhere.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

reference https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your class declaration. Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
     ...
}
```